# Group by operarion in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data-set having millions of rows and i need to apply the 'group by' operation in it using R.

The data is of the form

```
V1 V2 V3
a  u  1
a  v  2
b  w  3
b  x  4
c  y  5
c  z  6
```

performing 'group by' using R, I want to add up the values in column 3 and concatenate the values in column 2 like

```
V1 V2 V3
a uv 3
b wx 7
c yz 11
```

I have tried doing the opertaion in excel but due to a lot of tuples i can't use excel. I am new to R so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many possible ways to solve, here are two

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(V2 = paste(V2, collapse = ""), V3 = sum(V3)), by = V1]
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  a uv  3
# 2:  b wx  7
# 3:  c yz 11
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(V2 = paste(V2, collapse = ""), V3 = sum(V3))

# Source: local data table [3 x 3]
# 
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  a uv  3
# 2  b wx  7
# 3  c yz 11
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), V3 = 1:6), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option, using `aggregate`

```
# Group column 2
ag.2 <- aggregate(df$V2, by=list(df$V1), FUN = paste0, collapse = "")
# Group column 3
ag.3 <- aggregate(df$V3, by=list(df$V1), FUN = sum)

# Merge the two
res <- cbind(ag.2, ag.3[,-1])
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option with `sqldf`

```
 library(sqldf)
 sqldf('select V1,
        group_concat(V2,"") as V2,
        sum(V3) as V3 
        from df 
        group by V1')
 #  V1 V2 V3
 #1  a uv  3
 #2  b wx  7
 #3  c yz 11
```

Or using `base R`

```
 do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$V1), function(x) 
  with(x, data.frame(V1=V1[1L], V2= paste(V2, collapse=''), V3= sum(V3)))))
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it occurs to me — yet again — that sqldf is fundamentally a *terrible* idea. It’s essentially stringly typed data, except worse, stringly typed code. Don’t do this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Thanks for the comments.  I usually don't use `sqldf`, but I thought the `group_concat` would be a nice option.

Answer (score 2):

using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(V1), summarize, V2 = paste(V2, collapse=''), V3 = sum(V3))

#  V1 V2 V3
#1  a uv  3
#2  b wx  7
#3  c yz 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the groupBy function in the 'caroline' package:

```
x <-cbind.data.frame(V1=rep(letters[1:3],each=2), V2=letters[21:26], V3=1:6, stringsAsFactors=F) 
groupBy(df=x, clmns=c('V2','V3'),by='V1',aggregation=c('paste','sum'),collapse='')
```